# Two different approaches to delimit fields for a WHERE clause

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns, composition

I posted a more detailed version of this question on code review exchange, check this [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/222492/build-where-clause-for-search-conditions). I later got my implementation reviewed by one of my colleagues and he suggested a different approach to solve the problem. So this question is to help me find out, which of the two approaches should be picked and why?

If this is not suitable for StackOverflow and should still be in CodeReviewExchange, please let me know and I will move it there.

Also I want to say this in the beginning itself because I was criticized for this in my earlier post. The actual code is different than what I have provided here, its more complex so I had to simplify it to ask just what I want to figure out i.e. inheritance vs composition, which is better here?

Here is my set of classes:

```
public abstract class ConditionBuilder<TContext> : IConditionBuilder where TContext : FieldSearchContext
{
    public virtual bool QuotedValues { get; set; } = true;

    public abstract string OperatorSymbol { get; }

    public string BuildCondition(SearchCondition searchCondition)
    {
        var conditionBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        var context = searchCondition.GetContext<TContext>();

        conditionBuilder.Append(context.FieldId);
        conditionBuilder.Append(OperatorSymbol);
        conditionBuilder.Append(GetValue(context));

        return conditionBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public abstract bool CanHandle(FilterAction filterAction);

    public abstract object GetValue(TContext context);

}

public class TextLikeConditionBuilder : ConditionBuilder<TextContext>
{
    public override string OperatorSymbol => " LIKE ";

    public override bool CanHandle(FilterAction action) => action == FilterAction.TextLike;

    public override object GetValue(TextContext context)
    {
        if (context.Text == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return string.Concat("%", context.Text, "%");
    }
}

public class TextEqualsConditionBuilder : ConditionBuilder<TextContext>
{
    public override string OperatorSymbol => " = ";

    public override bool CanHandle(FilterAction action) => action == FilterAction.TextEqual;

    public override object GetValue(TextContext context)
    {
        return context.Text;
    }
}
```

In their default implementation the classes build a `WHERE` clause for `SQL`. These classes are consumed by other developers and can be overridden to build `WHERE` clause that is not necessarily meant for Database for example one can override `protected virtual StringBuilder GetCondition(SearchFilterCondition filterCondition, TContext context)` to build a `QUERY` for `Elasticsearch` also.

Coming back to the topic, in one particular instance where these classes are used with their default behavior, I wanted to delimit the `FieldId` so as to ensure that it works when `FieldId` contains spaces and special characters. This is how I implemented the solution:

```
public interface IDelimitedIdentifier
{
    string Delimit(string input);
}

internal class SqlServerDelimitedIdentifier : IDelimitedIdentifier
{
    public string Delimit(string input)
    {
        return "[" + input.Replace("]", "]]") + "]";
    }
}

internal class OracleDelimitedIdentifier : IDelimitedIdentifier
{
    public string Delimit(string input)
    {
        return "\"" + input + "\"";
    }
}

public abstract class ConditionBuilder<TContext> : IConditionBuilder where TContext : FieldSearchContext
{
    public virtual bool QuotedValues { get; set; } = true;

    public abstract string OperatorSymbol { get; }

    public string BuildCondition(SearchCondition searchCondition)
    {
        var conditionBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        var context = searchCondition.GetContext<TContext>();

        conditionBuilder.Append(SanitizeFieldId(context.FieldId));
        conditionBuilder.Append(OperatorSymbol);
        conditionBuilder.Append(GetValue(context));

        return conditionBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public abstract bool CanHandle(FilterAction filterAction);

    public abstract object GetValue(TContext context);

    protected virtual string SanitizeFieldId(string fieldId)
    {
        return _delimitedIdentifier.Delimit(fieldId);
    }

}

public class SanitizedFieldConditionBuilder<TContext> : ConditionBuilder<TContext> where TContext : FieldSearchContextBase
{
    private readonly ConditionBuilder<TContext> _baseConditionBuilder;
    private readonly IDelimitedIdentifier _delimitedIdentifier;

    public SanitizedFieldConditionBuilder(ConditionBuilder<TContext> baseConditionBuilder, IDelimitedIdentifier delimitedIdentifier)
    {
        QuotedValues = false;

        _baseConditionBuilder = baseConditionBuilder;
        _delimitedIdentifier = delimitedIdentifier;
    }

    public override string OperatorSymbol => _baseConditionBuilder.OperatorSymbol;

    public override bool CanHandle(SearchFilterAction action) => _baseConditionBuilder.CanHandle(action);

    public override object GetValue(TContext context) => _baseConditionBuilder.GetValue(context);

    protected override string SanitizeFieldId(string fieldId)
    {
        return _delimitedIdentifier.Delimit(fieldId);
    }
}

public static class ConditionBuilderExtensions
{
    public static SanitizedFieldConditionBuiler<TContext> SanitizeField<TContext>(this ConditionBuilder<TContext> source, IColumnSanitizer columnSanitizer) where TContext : FieldSearchContext
    {
        return new SanitizedFieldConditionBuiler<TContext>(source, columnSanitizer);
    }

    public static ParameterizedConditionBuilder<TContext> WithParameters<TContext>(this ConditionBuilder<TContext> source,
        ParameterCollection parameterCollection, bool parameterizeNullValues = false) where TContext : FieldSearchContext
    {
        return new ParameterizedConditionBuilder<TContext>(source, parameterCollection, parameterizeNullValues);
    }
}
```

The classes can be instantiated as shown below:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   var conditionBuilders = new List<IConditionBuilder>()
        {
            new TextEqualsConditionBuilder().SanitizeField(new SqlServerDelimitedIdentifier()),
            new TextLikeConditionBuilder().SanitizeField(new SqlServerDelimitedIdentifier())
        };
        }
}
```

My colleague suggested to use composition instead of extension. Here is how the classes would look like as per his recommendation.

```
 public abstract class ConditionBuilder<TContext> : IConditionBuilder where TContext : FieldSearchContext
    {
        private readonly IDelimitedIdentifier DelimitedIdentifier;

        public virtual bool QuotedValues { get; set; } = true;

        public abstract string OperatorSymbol { get; }

        protected ConditionBuilder(IDelimitedIdentifier delimitedIdentifier)
        {
            DelimitedIdentifier = delimitedIdentifier;
        }

        public string BuildCondition(SearchCondition searchCondition)
        {
            var conditionBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            var context = searchCondition.GetContext<TContext>();

            conditionBuilder.Append(DelimitedIdentifier.Delimit(context.FieldId));
            conditionBuilder.Append(OperatorSymbol);
            conditionBuilder.Append(GetValue(context));

            return conditionBuilder.ToString();
        }

        public abstract bool CanHandle(FilterAction filterAction);

        public abstract object GetValue(TContext context);

    }

    public class TextLikeConditionBuilder : ConditionBuilder<TextContext>
    {

        public TextLikeConditionBuilder(IDelimitedIdentifier delimitedIdentifier) : base(delimitedIdentifier)
        {

        }

        public override string OperatorSymbol => " LIKE ";

        public override bool CanHandle(FilterAction action) => action == FilterAction.TextLike;

        public override object GetValue(TextContext context)
        {
            if (context.Text == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return string.Concat("%", context.Text, "%");
        }
    }

    public class TextEqualsConditionBuilder : ConditionBuilder<TextContext>
    {

        public TextEqualsConditionBuilder(IDelimitedIdentifier delimitedIdentifier) : base(delimitedIdentifier)
        {

        }

        public override string OperatorSymbol => " = ";

        public override bool CanHandle(FilterAction action) => action == FilterAction.TextEqual;

        public override object GetValue(TextContext context)
        {
            if (context.Text == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return context.Text;
        }
    }
```

Here are my arguments for why it shouldn't be done as per what my colleague recommends doing:

1. `IDelimitedIdentifier` is very specific to database, why should it be moved inside the base class when the functionality can be supported using extension.

   2. Extension reduces the number of changes otherwise adding that constructor would mean changing all derived classes and let me tell you that there are 15 odd deriving classes
   3. Isn't adding a constructor against Open-Closed principle?

EDIT: Since so many people are concerned about the SQL Injection issue here, rather than answering what I asked, I am adding this additional code that takes care of it. I have also updated the ConditionBuilderExtensions class defined above.

```
public class ParameterizedConditionBuilder<TContext> : ConditionBuilder<TContext>
        where TContext : FieldSearchContext
    {
        private readonly ConditionBuilder<TContext> baseConditionBuilder;
        private readonly ParameterCollection parameterCollection;
        private readonly bool parameterizeNullValues;

        public override bool QuotedValues { get; set; } = false;

        public ParameterizedConditionBuilder(ConditionBuilder<TContext> baseConditionBuilder,
            ParameterCollection parameterCollection, bool parameterizeNullValues = false)
        {
            this.baseConditionBuilder = baseConditionBuilder;
            this.parameterCollection = parameterCollection;
            this.parameterizeNullValues = parameterizeNullValues;
        }

        public override bool CanHandle(FilterAction action) => baseConditionBuilder.CanHandle(action);
        public override string OperatorSymbol => baseConditionBuilder.OperatorSymbol;

        public override object GetValue(TContext context)
        {
            object val = baseConditionBuilder.GetValue(context);
            if (val == null && !parameterizeNullValues)
            {
                return null;
            }

            string p = parameterCollection.AddParameter(val);
            return p;
        }
    }
```

Here is how I build my conditions and then use them in DBCommand. Its immune to SQL Injection

```
private static DbCommand CreateDbCommand(Database database, MergeOperation mergeOperation, IList<SearchCondition> searchCondition)
        {
            var whereConditions = new List<string>();

            ParameterCollection paramCollection = new ParameterCollection("{{{0}}}");

            var conditionBuilders = new List<IConditionBuilder>()
            {
                new TextEqualsConditionBuilder().WithParameters(paramCollection).SanitizeField(new SqlSanitizer()),
                new TextLikeConditionBuilder().WithParameters(paramCollection).SanitizeField(new SqlSanitizer())
            };

            foreach (var condition in searchCondition)
            {
                var context = condition.GetContext<FieldSearchContext>();
                var conditionBuilder = conditionBuilders.FirstOrDefault(u => u.CanHandle(condition.FilterAction));
                whereConditions.Add(conditionBuilder.BuildCondition(condition));
            }

            SqlBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlBuilder();

            sqlBuilder.SELECT("Id");
            sqlBuilder.FROM("Students");
            if (whereConditions.Count > 0)
            {
                sqlBuilder.WHERE(string.Join(Convert.ToString(" " + mergeOperation + " "), whereConditions), paramCollection.GetParameters().Select(pair => pair.Value).ToArray());
            }

            DbExtensions.Database sqlBuilderDb = new DbExtensions.Database(database.CreateConnection());
            IDbCommand sqlBuilderCommand = sqlBuilderDb.CreateCommand(sqlBuilder);

            DbCommand databaseCommand = database.GetSqlStringCommand(sqlBuilderCommand.CommandText);
            if (sqlBuilderCommand.Parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (IDataParameter dataParameter in sqlBuilderCommand.Parameters)
                {
                    database.AddInParameter(databaseCommand, dataParameter.ParameterName, dataParameter.DbType, dataParameter.Value);
                }
            }

            return databaseCommand;
        }
```

SqlBuilder is from a nuget package DBExtensions. I use Microsoft.Enterprise.Library.Data for database access.

EDIT 2: Removed the code that was subjected to SQL Injection

Comment: Technique A vs Technique B?  None of it really matters if they're both vulnerable to SQL injection, and you were told very clearly that SQL injection was an issue with this code. The house is burning and you're worried if the roses are properly trimmed.

Comment: I glanced over all of the code. I know the answer to this question is in there, but it might be easier if you spelled it out. What do you mean by 'delimiting the fields for a WHERE clause?' A WHERE clause has conditions, not fields. How or why is delimiting fields that will be used in a WHERE clause different from delimiting fields that won't be used in a WHERE clause? Perhaps it's in there, but it's more work to read all of that code and try to figure out how it relates to the question. (And yes, SQL injection.)

Comment: @madreflection I added the code that takes care of the burning house. Jokes aside, the code was not added earlier because I didn't know that it will be pointed out so much. Thanks for you feedback

Comment: @ScottHannen Thanks for asking. So by fields I meant the left hand side of a where condition i.e. the column names. Now these classes are used only for building the WHERE clause and that's why the question is specifically for delimiting those fields that will be in WHERE clause. The conditions are instantiatied based on filters that are provided by end user

Comment: Except you haven't. As pointed out in code review, the problem exists at `return "'" + context.Text + "'";` in `GetValue` because that's where the conversion from *string value* to *string expression* occurs. Regarding jokes: SQL injection is a major attack vector so SO is very vocal about it. Many, many jokes and analogies are used on SO to make the point because it needs to strike a dissonant chord to get the proper attention (and it's still quite often ignored). Plus, it gets very repetitive.

Comment: @madreflection Thank you once again. I edited the answer and removed it for once and all

Comment: I fear you've only hidden it from SO and not addressed the underlying issue, but if that's really the case, so be it. As for the question at hand, I agree with @ScottHannen that there's a lot to read here. It's very dense code and anyone who really wants to provide an answer is in for a fairly big time commitment. I remember writing something like this in Classic ASP (with proper expression escaping) and was happy to abandon this degree of direct query construction in strings some 18+ years ago. Good luck.

Comment: Of course I have addressed, `ParameterizedConditionBuilder` is meant to take care of the parameter substitution. It's ok if you don't wan't to answer due to time constraints. Thanks again!